# PHP front end and Django backend?

Tags: php, django

I need to replace the front end portion of our site with PHP that uses some Ajax calls, but the backend uses Django for db calls.  I'm hesitant about using PHP and Django together, so I was wondering if anyone has experience doing so?  Anything I should be aware of when integrating the two, for instance, urls that are mapped in the application?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with *frontend*? PHP is a server-side language. Ajax calls are done by JavaScript. You can use this with Django too.

Comment: There is a port of the templating portion of Django to PHP called H2o which might be of use to you http://www.h2o-template.org/ although it is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no worry.

You can inspectdb from django, that generates models, add admin files and you can use that for admin purposes.

There are many such projects including the [django backend for wordpress](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/lakshman-prasad)